# Why does GCC store global and static int differently?

Tags: c, gcc, objdump

Here is my C program with one static, two global, one local and one extern variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gvar1;
int gvar2 = 12;
extern int evar = 1;
int main(void)
{
    int lvar;
    static int svar = 4;
    lvar = 2;
    gvar1 = 3;
    printf ("global1-%d global2-%d local+1-%d static-%d extern-%d\n", gvar1, gvar2, (lvar+1), svar, evar);
return 0;
}
```

Note that gvar1, gvar2, evar, lvar and svar are all defined as integers.

I disassembled the code using objdump and the debug_str for this shows as below:

```
Contents of section .debug_str:
 0000 76617269 61626c65 732e6300 6c6f6e67  variables.c.long
 0010 20756e73 69676e65 6420696e 74002f75   unsigned int./u
 0020 73657273 2f686f6d 6534302f 72616f70  sers/home40/raop
 0030 2f626b75 702f6578 616d706c 65730075  /bkup/examples.u
 0040 6e736967 6e656420 63686172 00737661  nsigned char.sva
 0050 72006d61 696e006c 6f6e6720 696e7400  r.main.long int.
 0060 6c766172 0073686f 72742075 6e736967  lvar.short unsig
 0070 6e656420 696e7400 67766172 31006776  ned int.gvar1.gv
 0080 61723200 65766172 00474e55 20432034  ar2.evar.GNU C 4
 0090 2e342e36 20323031 31303733 31202852  .4.6 20110731 (R
 00a0 65642048 61742034 2e342e36 2d332900  ed Hat 4.4.6-3).
 00b0 73686f72 7420696e 7400               short int.
```

Why is it showing the following?

```
unsigned char.svar
long int.lvar
short unsigned int.gvar1.gvar2.evar
```

How does GCC decide which type it should be stored as?

I am using GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)

Comment: ... Probably they are just symbol table or some information for debugging, unrelated to the type of the variable. Especially when they appear to be sorted in reverse lexicographical order.

Comment: Most of those dots are misleading. If you look at the hex codes, very few are the real dot character `0x2e`. Most are `NUL` terminators `0x00`. So for example, in the sequence `unsigned char.svar.main.`, all of the dots are `NUL` terminators. Which means those are three unrelated strings.

Comment: Could you explain why the layout of the data segment matters to you? What is motivating your question?

Comment: Eeh? That's not a disassembly of the program, it is a hex dump of some object or debug file. In order to use objdump I believe you have to give it the actual executable. Many tool chains provide the option to disassemble through the debugger, for example through gdb. Use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it showing the following?

Simple answer: It is not showing what you think but it is showing:

```
1 "variables.c"
2 "long unsigned int"
2a "unsigned int"
2b "int"
3 "/users/home40/raop/bkup/examples"
4 "unsigned char"
4a "char"
5 "svar"
6 "main"
7 "long int"
8 "lvar"
9 "short unsigned int"
10 "gvar1"
11 "gvar2"
12 "evar"
13 "GNU C 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)"
14 "short int"
```

The section is named `.debug_str`; it contains a list of strings which are separated by NUL bytes. These strings are **in any order** and they are referenced by the section `.debug_info`. So the fact that `svar` is following `unsigned char` has **no meaning at all**.

The `.debug_info` section contains the actual debugging information. This section does not contain strings. Instead it will contain information like this:

```
    ...
Item 123:
    Type of information: Data type
    Name: 2b /* String #2b in ".debug_str" is "int" */
    Kind of data type: Signed integer
    Number of bits: 32
    ... some more information ...
Item 124:
    Type of information: Global variable
    Name: 8 /* "lvar" */
    Data type defined by: Item 123
    Stored at: Address 0x1234
    ... some more information ...
Begin item 125:
    Type of information: Function
    Name: 6 /* "main" */
    ... some more information ...
Item 126:
    Type of information: Local variable
    Name: 5 /* "svar" */
    Data type defined by: Item 123
    Stored at: Address 0x1238
    ... some more information ...
End item 125 /* Function "main" */
Item 127:
    ...
```

You can see this information using the following command:

```
readelf --debug-dump filename.o
```

> Why does GCC store global and static int differently?

I compiled your example twice: Once with optimization and once without optimization.

Without optimization `svar` and `gvar1` were stored **exactly** the same way: Data type `int`, stored on a fixed address. `lvar` was: Data type `int`, stored on the stack.

With optimization `lvar` and `svar` were stored the same way: Data type: `int`, not stored at all, instead they are treated as constant value.

(This makes sense because the values of these variables never change.)

Answer (score 3):

The [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) specification (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) -or older C standards- does not define at what addresses or offsets are stored global or static variables, so the implementation (your `gcc` compiler and your `ld` linker) is free to put them at any place.

**The organization and layout of the [data segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) is an implementation detail.**

You may want to read more about [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) to understand debug information, which is useful to the `gdb` debugger.

You may want to read more about [*linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/), and about the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, if you want to understand how they are working. On Linux, there are several utilities to inspect [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) files, including [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html).

Notice that your GCC4.4 is an obsolete and old version of GCC. Current version is [GCC7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/), and GCC8 will be released in a few weeks (spring 2018). I strongly recommend to upgrade your compiler.

If you need to understand how and why the data segments are organized in such way and why your implementation chooses such a layout, you could take advantage that both `gcc` and `ld` (from [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/)) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and study their source in details. You'll need many years of work, since they are complex software (more than ten million lines of source code).

If you happen to start studying the internals of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to study a recent version. Most people of the GCC community have probably forgotten the details of GCC4.4 (released in 2009). A lot of things have changed in GCC since that ancient thing. A few years ago, I have written many slides about GCC internals, see the [documentation of GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html).

BTW, the layout of data segments, or of variables inside them, might vary with [optimization options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). It might happen that `lvar` does not sit in memory (e.g. stays in a register only); it could happen that a static variable is removed (using something like the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)) etc.

For a *single* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) `foo.c`, you might compile it into assembler code using `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O foo.c` and look into the emitted `foo.s` assembler code.

To understand more how your `ld` linker work, you might look into some relevant [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html). You could find how `ld` is invoked from `gcc` by using `gcc -v` (instead of `gcc`) in your compilation and linking command.

In most cases, **you should not care** about the particular offsets (in [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) or [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)) or addresses (in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) of global or static variables. Be also aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). The [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem can be used to understand your process.

<sup>(your question is severely lacking some motivation and context)</sup>